# Pegar valor de um dado e jogar na var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estou desenvolvendo um web server em CLP , nele será capaz de pegar os dados de uma mangueira de ar, pra saber se a pressão está ok.
Desenvolvi o codigo no js e setei um valor pra ver se funcionava, porem agora quero pegar o valor dessa pressão e se atingir determinado numero, ele vá para a pagina em questão

segue o codigo

```
$('#bot).on('
click ',function(){
})

var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
            $('counter').text(i);
            i++;
            if (i == 6) {
                $('#pag-1).show();
                    $('pag-2).hide();
                    }
                }, 1000)
```

no `var i`, vocês sabem que função uso pra puxar os dados de determinado local?

Comment: Quando você fala "puxar os dados de determinado local" seria puxar o valor de um input (campo de um formulário)? Se sim, basta utilizar o seguinte var i = $('#idCampo').val();

Comment: isso, porem os valores estão sendo puxados de um programa em tempo real, no caso de id campo eu teria que setar um valor pra quando o programa chegasse á ele, identificasse?

Comment: Sim, o campo em questão de onde ele vai puxar teria que ter um id.

Comment: demoro, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a sua intenção é pegar o `value` de um `input`, basta fazer o seguinte:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   var i = $('#numero').val(); 

   console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Número <input type="text" id="numero" value="5">
```

Comment: valeu Cara mas onde eu determino a entrada desse imput? se o valor será jogado em tempo real

Comment: Esse valor virá de um código PHP? Se sim, pode fazer o seguinte:

Número <input type="text" id="numero" value="<?php echo $variavelComValor; ?>">

Comment: na realidade esse valor está sendo gerado no tia portal, dentro de um CLP que estou fazendo para um web server, minha dificuldade é justamente essa, como pegar esse valor do CLP e jogar em uma html

Comment: Teria que ver como funciona esse CLP para ver como ele trabalha com os dados e conseguir encontrar uma forma de passar o valor para o input no formulário.

Comment: Leandro no seguinte codigo var i = $('#counter').val(); SetInterval( function () { i++; if ( i = 5000000 ) { o que você acha que não está rolando? consegui jogar o valor pra tela em tempo real, porem agora so preciso pegar aquele valor especifico e jogar uma ação como nesse exemplo ai